# Is there a solid/known way to connect r/c model components?

Tags: raspbian, hardware

I am just starting out with my Raspberry Pi and I was wondering if it is possible to connect r/c model components to my raspberry and control them with raspbian/node.js.

The quality and pricing of engines like these

http://www.conrad.nl/ce/nl/product/517229/Dualsky-Brushless-motor-Dualsky-XMotor-2830-8omwmin-per-Volt-1350-turns-6?ref=list

and servos like

http://www.conrad.nl/ce/nl/product/275460/Modelcraft-Micro-servo-MC1811-Glijlagers-Aandrijving-Kunststof-JR/?ref=category&rt=category&rb=1

really draw my attention.

Is there a solid/known way to do this? My search attempts haven't returned me a lot of useful information yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most PWM control of servos and ESCs, you'll want to use PIGPIO:

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/

It's hugely versatile and pretty easy to use. It also has a lot of help if you're planning on controlling stuff from C programs. Try searching on the Raspi forums for more detail, there's loads on there.

An ESC is something that you'll need to buy to go in between the Pi and the motor, that will translate the PWM from the pi's GPIO (sent using PIGPIO) to something the motor understands. To power the motor you'll also need a LiPo battery with a C rating higher than the motor's current draw.

Servos are also ridiculously easy, also use PIGPIO but you can send the pulses directly to them.

Comment: nice I should be able to use this